# Are Multi-line Options in Html Select Tags Possible?

Tags: html, html-select

Is it possible (using HTML only) to display `select` with `option`s that span multiple lines each?

Comment: I do not think it is possible using just the `select` and option `tags`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line Break in HTML Select Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is not possible using html select control.

You can use a div that can act as a dropdown list using JavaScript and css.

Comment: If you want construct your list from database, dropdown doesn't seems a solution.

Answer (score 5):

not only is it not possible on standard html, but it would then (as an object) become incompatible with the way IOS devices handle the ***option tag***, which is to display a scroll list so it is not even reasonable to want the ***option tag*** to behave that way as it would break cross-device compatibility badly and unexpectedly.

as others have answered (i dont have enough reputation to upvote or comment yet) have said, it must be done with css/div styling etc and in that way is a lot more extensible with full html functionality within each of the ***option tag***'s as well as (via css styling) being mobile device friendly.

Answer (score 3):

If your case is around iOS truncating long option text, then the solution from [How to fix truncated text on <select> element on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398154/how-to-fix-truncated-text-on-select-element-on-ios7) can help.

> Add an empty optgroup at the end of the select list:

You can implement like this:

```
<select>
  <option selected="" disabled="">option first</option>
  <option>another option that is really long and will probably be truncated on a mobile device</option>
  ...
  <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the presentation of a `select` element is up to the user agent, I'm afraid you can't have that, unless some UA actually implements it. But `select` as either a ListBox or ComboBox never really had much need for items spanning multiple lines. Furthermore it would greatly confuse users as they are used to one line = one item.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You could use radio buttons instead though, their `<label>`s can word wrap.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible by using some JavaScript with CSS styling on HTML elements, easily done with a framework like Dojo Toolkit. Otherwise, use Radio or Checkbox controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of options and for that reason looking for multi-line possibility, then there is another trick that can be helpful. Instead of using **select** and **option** tag, use **datalist** and **option** tag. By this, users can search for their option inside the select area.

```
<input list="stocks" name="stockArea" placeholder="hello">
<label for="stockArea">Select Your Stock</label>
<datalist id="stocks">
  <option value="Microsoft" >
  <option value="Lenovo">
  <option value="Apple">
  <option value="Twitter">
  <option value="Amazon">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -7):

What about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select size="13" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but maybe it could help you.

If you want to select multiple options, you must press Ctrl + click to select more options.

If you want to disable multiselect, just erase the "multiple" parameter from the SELECT tag.

Comment: **NOT** multi-select, it's multi-line what he is looking for as he stated in his question.

Comment: Yes, I provided a extra information. the multi-line it's given by the "size" attribute. A i said: "If you want to disable de multiselect, just erase the "multiple" parameter from the SELECT tag."

Comment: This (duplicate) question gives a good example of what's being asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368502/how-can-i-build-a-select-with-multiline-options