# Html.ListBoxFor with multiline items

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

is it possible to make ASP.NET Html.ListBoxFor to work with multiline items ? Because right now i have a list of strings, some strings are very long, so they do not fit into list box, and are cut, i.e, instead of "qwertyuiop" i see only "qwer". The width of the list box cannot be changed, that's how it must be. Can i make it to show a single item/string over multiple lines(i tried inserting new line symbol, html line break symbol into string, doesn't work) ? Or do i have to use some other html element for that instead of Html.ListBoxFor ?

Edit:
My code is:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.MyFriendsIdList, new SelectList(this.Model.MyFriendsDisplayList, "Id", "Name"), new { id = "FriendsSourceList" })
```

Anyway, i'm gonna need to make a multiline listbox plus i need to have ability to search/filter through items and hide/show them as i type text in search text field. Any recomendations ?

Edit: newest code example :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- none of these styles work on ff or ie9... -->
    <style>
        select {
            -ms-word-break: break-all;
            -ms-word-wrap: break-all;
            -webkit-word-break: break-word;
            -webkit-word-wrap: break-word;
            word-break: break-word;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            -webkit-hyphens: auto;
            -moz-hyphens: auto;
            hyphens: auto;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
            white-space: -pre-wrap;
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
    <head>
        <title>Site Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 style="margin-left:100px;">My List Box Source Example</h1>
        <!-- In style, "word-wrap:break-word" makes items appear over multiple lines if needed, works only on chrome, ff and ie9 broken -->
        <select name="sometext" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px; height:250px; resize:none; margin-left:100px;" id="mylist">
            <option value="1">VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456END</option>
            <option value="3">Text1</option>
            <option value="5">Text2</option>
            <option value="6">Text3</option>
            <option value="7">Text4</option>
            <option value="9">Text5</option>
            <option value="12">abc6</option>
            <option value="14">SomeRandomText</option>
            <option value="45">ghi8</option>
            <option value="16">jkl9</option>
            <option value="11">zzz</option>
            <option value="32">xxx</option>
            <option value="73">LastItemHere</option>
        </select>
        
        <h2 style="margin-left:100px;">Search field</h2>
        <textarea rows="2" cols="45" style="margin-left:100px; resize:none; overflow-y:hidden;" id="searchfield"></textarea><br /><br />
        <input id="FilterButton" type="submit" style="margin-left:200px; width: 125px" value="Filter List" class="radius button"/><br /><br />
        <input id="HideButton" type="submit" style="margin-left:200px; width: 195px" value="Hide items that contains" class="radius button"/>
        
        <h2 style="margin-left:100px;">My Text Area Example</h2>
        <textarea rows="3" cols="45" style="margin-left:100px; resize:none; overflow-y:hidden;" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
 
        <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Titles - when mouse over entry
            options = document.getElementById("mylist").getElementsByTagName("option");

            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                options[i].title = options[i].text;
            }
            
            $("#FilterButton").click(function (x) {
                x.preventDefault();
                
                //var size = document.getElementById("searchfield").rows;
                //console.log("size : " + size);
                //document.getElementById("searchfield").rows = size + 1;
                
                //Search and hide works on chrome and ff, ie9 broken
                var searchText = $("#searchfield").val();
                var list = document.getElementById("mylist");
                for (var c = 0; c < list.length; c++) {
                    if(searchText != null && searchText != '') {
                        var index = list[c].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
                        if(index >= 0) {
                            $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').hide();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').show();
                    }
                }
            });
            
            $("#HideButton").click(function (x) {
                x.preventDefault();
                var searchText = $("#searchfield").val();
                var list = document.getElementById("mylist");
                for (var c = 0; c < list.length; c++) {
                    if(searchText != null && searchText != '') {
                        var index = list[c].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
                        if(index >= 0) {
                            $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you give us sample so I Help you ..

Comment: Start with this: how would you do that with just plain HTML?

Comment: Html.ListBoxFor is same as "select" tag in plain html. I read some posts, and it seems that it doesnt really support multiline entries... Is there any other html element, that could do that ?

Comment: This is just a styling issue. Add some css. Look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743676/html-listbox-wrap-text)

Comment: I made it to work on chrome, but ff and ie9 are completely broken... if anyone wants to help me to make any kind of word break style to work on ff or ie9, here is my current example html code, you will also need jquery 2.1.1 : http://txs.io/1W2b . Also, i made it possible to hide and show items in select by text. It works on chrome and ff, but ie9 doesnt do anything. Also, im trying to make that text area at the bottom to auto expand/shrink when writing into it, nothing works good for now, only found a few broken libraries...