# How to wrap the options of a select dropdown

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word wrap options in a select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list)

i have a standard select dropdown with width set to 250px.However the options length is very big i want to restrict it to 250 and the text to wrap

eg

```
<select>
<option>OPtion 1</option>
<option>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think it is not possible, look at this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list

Comment: Standard drop down elements do not support word wrapping, so you're out of luck. Either trim the text with server side or client side code, or use some plugin to emulate drop down.