# Wrapping html select option

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is is possible to wrap long text inside ?

```
<select><option value="1">A very long text that needs to be wrapped</option></select>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3587942/218196.

Answer (score 0):

Untested.. but you could try assigning an id to that option.

```
<option id="longtext" value="1">
```

and then in css try something like

```
#longtext { width: 50%; }
```

or

```
#longtext { width: 200px; }
```

or

```
#longtext { width: 300px; height: 200px; }
```