# Is there a CSS property which acts like android XML "wrap content"?

Tags: css, android-layout, gwt

In particular I have a GWT project with a

1. TextArea element which I want to conform to a set width and expand as much as needed to the bottom.
2. ListBox element which I want to conform to a set width and expand vertically to show the entirety of the displayed list item.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two widgets using *replaced elements*: `<textarea>` and `<select>` respectively.

1. for the `TextArea`, there's no way to make it really "resize automatically" other than listening to events and computing the new size (there's actually no need to *compute* the new size, you can just let the browser do it; see http://phaistonian.pblogs.gr/expanding-textareas-the-easy-and-clean-way.html)
2. for the `ListBox`, it's impossible to have the items' text wrap. See [Word wrap options in a select list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3587942/116472) for a similar question in pure JS.

Comment: Thanks Thomas perhaps I didn't explain about the ListBox. I want the entire Item to be displayed while controlling the width

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the item labels to wrap? [Impossible I'm afraid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3587942/116472).

Comment: Ok impossible seems drastic. I think so, but in GWT they are buffered from me. how do I access them

Comment: I tried the css elemt from your link it doesn't seem to work for me what am I doing wrong? .textarea {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 8px;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 outline: none;
 resize: none;
 font-size: 120%;
 height: 3em;
 min-height: 3em;
 max-height: 100em;
 width: 30em;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Read the blog post: it's not about the stylesheet, it's about JS and events.

Comment: Ok I read and implemented. Please replace the 2cnd item in your answer with your 2cnd comment and I will accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the width to whatever number and set height to `auto`.