# Full name is not visible in twin-column values in Vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin

I'm new to vaadin. I came across with a bug that full name is not visible in twin-column component's values. I have very long names inside the left side of the twin-column. I increased the width of the component much as I can. But still some lines are there that not visible full name.
I tried to add some css, even that didn't work.

```
.v-select-twincol-options .v-select-twincol-break-word{word-wrap: break-word;}
```

I tried with this css line. Any wrong in here? Or any idea to solve this. Please help me on this..

Thank you in advance.

[image: twin-column]

```
private TwinColSelect createTemplateSelectTwinColumn()
    {
        TwinColSelect twinColSelect = new TwinColSelect("Related Templates");
        twinColSelect.setNullSelectionAllowed(true);
        twinColSelect.setMultiSelect(true);
        twinColSelect.setImmediate(true);
        twinColSelect.setSizeFull();

        Collection<File> templates = getTemplates();

        Collections.sort((List<File>) templates, new Comparator<File>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(final File f1, final File f2)
            {
                return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
            }
        });

        for (File file : templates)
        {
            twinColSelect.addItem(file.getNodeId());
            twinColSelect.setItemCaption(file.getNodeId(), file.getName());
        }

        return twinColSelect;
    }
```

Method where I'm creating the twinColumn inside a `FormLayout`

Comment: Vaadin is a server-side framework – the problem is client-side however. So please show client-side code that reproduces the problem, or at least an online example.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for quick reply. see the edited answer. I didn't get what you say. I hope edited answer helps you. Anyway I want just show the full names inside the twin column. Even in wrapped format. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin's TwinColSelect eventually results in two standard HTML option list controls in the DOM; see the DOM of this example: http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/#component.select.twincolselect.basic

[image: DOM structure of Vaadin's TwinColSelect]

`word-wrap` is, however, [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list) on option list items.

Consider creating your "own" TwinColSelect from two Vaadin tables. Vaadin tables are much more flexible regarding CSS styling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see. I realized it. I'll give up this `word-wrap` and trying in some other way.