# How to wrap options in drop down list in MVC view

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

How to do word wrap for options in dropdownlist in MVC.
I have tried the css as below

```
select.business {
  text-indent: 0.01px!important;
  text-overflow: 'ellipsis'!important;
  overflow: hidden!important;
  overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
 option.business{
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 250px !important;
  word-wrap:break-word !important;
  word-break: break-all!important;
  white-space: pre-wrap!important;
  overflow-x: hidden!important;
  max-width: 200px!important;
}
```

But still the styling on Option has no effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word wrap options in a select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list)

Comment: What is your `view` code?