# Wrap the text into the next line for Drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have created a drop down in which the first element length is very high and when i executed it the text in element expands more than that of drop down area . Is there any way of making the text for element into next and with the same width of drop down

```js
var name1 = "Ajnjkbndgjkdrhgkhtgjkdrhtjkrhtukhrtjkjerthrjklthkretklejkltjrkltjekltjklejtklejrkltjerkltjklert kqh4ui3hui4h23uio4 uiheruiwhruio3h 2ruihuihw3uirh34uirhuioh e riohewiorh wioriorh weuiohriowe4",
    name2 = "B",
    name3 = "C";

var s = document.getElementById('names');
s.children[0].innerText = name1;
s.children[1].innerText = name2;
s.children[2].innerText = name3;
```

```css
.setMyWidth{width: 5000px;}
```

```html
<select id="names" style=width:500px class='setMyWidth'>
    <option value="a">fill1</option>
    <option value="b">fill2</option>
    <option value="c">fill3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think, this is possible. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word wrap options in a select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customise width of a `option`, if you want to achieve this then you can use custom select plugins like

1. https://select2.github.io/examples.html
2. https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

See Chosen Demo in the below snippet.

```js
var name1 = "Ajnjkbndgjkdrhgkhtgjkdrhtjkrhtukhrtjkjerthrjklthkretklejkltjrkltjekltjklejtklejrkltjerkltjklert kqh4ui3hui4h23uio4 uiheruiwhruio3h 2ruihuihw3uirh34uirhuioh e riohewiorh wioriorh weuiohriowe4",
  name2 = "B",
  name3 = "C";

var s = document.getElementById('names');
s.children[0].innerText = name1;
s.children[1].innerText = name2;
s.children[2].innerText = name3;

$("#names").chosen({
  width: "200px"
});
```

```css
/*!
Chosen, a Select Box Enhancer for jQuery and Prototype
by Patrick Filler for Harvest, http://getharvest.com

Version 1.6.2
Full source at https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen
Copyright (c) 2011-2016 Harvest http://getharvest.com

MIT License, https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/LICENSE.md
This file is generated by `grunt build`, do not edit it by hand.
*/


/* @group Base */

.chosen-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.chosen-container * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: 1010;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
  left: 0;
}

.chosen-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chosen-container .search-choice .group-name,
.chosen-container .chosen-single .group-name {
  margin-right: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #999999;
}

.chosen-container .search-choice .group-name:after,
.chosen-container .chosen-single .group-name:after {
  content: ":";
  padding-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* @end */


/* @group Single Chosen */

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(52%, #eeeeee), color-stop(100%, #f4f4f4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px white inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-default {
  color: #999;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 26px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single-with-deselect span {
  margin-right: 38px;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 26px;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') -42px 1px no-repeat;
  font-size: 1px;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}

.chosen-container-single.chosen-disabled .chosen-single abbr:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 100%;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 0px 2px;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-search {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1010;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: white url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-drop {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}


/* @end */


/* @group Results */

.chosen-container .chosen-results {
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  max-height: 240px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 6px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 15px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result {
  display: list-item;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li.disabled-result {
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
  background-color: #3875d7;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #3875d7), color-stop(90%, #2a62bc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  color: #fff;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li.no-results {
  color: #777;
  display: list-item;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-result {
  display: list-item;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-option {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-results li em {
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* @end */


/* @group Multi Chosen */

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(1%, #eeeeee), color-stop(15%, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  cursor: text;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 25px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3px 5px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px 20px 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(50%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(52%, #e8e8e8), color-stop(100%, #eeeeee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-size: 100% 19px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px white inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #333;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: default;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') -42px 1px no-repeat;
  font-size: 1px;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-disabled {
  padding-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(50%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(52%, #e8e8e8), color-stop(100%, #eeeeee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  color: #666;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-focus {
  background: #d4d4d4;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-focus .search-choice-close {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-results {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-drop .result-selected {
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}


/* @end */


/* @group Active  */

.chosen-container-active .chosen-single {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #eeeeee), color-stop(80%, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
}

.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
  border-left: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: -18px 2px;
}

.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  color: #222 !important;
}


/* @end */


/* @group Disabled Support */

.chosen-disabled {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  cursor: default;
}

.chosen-disabled .chosen-single {
  cursor: default;
}

.chosen-disabled .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
  cursor: default;
}


/* @end */


/* @group Right to Left */

.chosen-rtl {
  text-align: right;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-single {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-single span {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 26px;
  direction: rtl;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-single-with-deselect span {
  margin-left: 38px;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-single div {
  right: auto;
  left: 3px;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-single abbr {
  right: auto;
  left: 26px;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li {
  float: right;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  direction: rtl;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
  margin: 3px 5px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 19px;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  right: auto;
  left: 4px;
}

.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search,
.chosen-rtl .chosen-drop {
  left: 9999px;
}

.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single .chosen-results {
  margin: 0 0 4px 4px;
  padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-results li.group-option {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
  border-right: none;
}

.chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
  padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px;
  background: white url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px;
  direction: rtl;
}

.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: 6px 2px;
}

.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: -12px 2px;
}


/* @end */


/* @group Retina compatibility */

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi),
only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-down span,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-up span {
    background-image: url('chosen-sprite@2x.png') !important;
    background-size: 52px 37px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  }
}


/* @end */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select id="names" style="width:500px" class='setMyWidth'>
    <option value="a">fill1</option>
    <option value="b">fill2</option>
    <option value="c">fill3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is coming here now, I didn't manage to make Rohan Kumar answer work (that's probably my bad), but I found another way to solve it.
One simple modification to **chosen.css** file:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

It does not wrap text into next line but I think it can be considered a solution too.