# Bootstrap select dropdown width issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

Hello i am using bootstrap vue select in a modal.

The issue i am facing is the width of the select options dropdown overlaps the modal width.

```
  <b-modal ref="myModalRef" :modal-class="myclass" size="lg">
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <b-select id="input-horizontal" class="ipt-category" size="sm">
     <option data-content="Methodology">aaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
     <option>vv</option>
     <option>cc</option>
  </b-select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/g8ry6x51/5/

Any help would be appreciated to set the width of dropdown within the modal width and break the options text maybe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word wrap options in a select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list)

Comment: No wordwrap doesn't works