# How to add a Line Break for label in of f:selectItems

Tags: jsf

I am usin SelectOneMenu, in which the selectItems will load from database. The labele values are very large to fit in browser, So i wanted to split the label into multiple lines. Please let me know wether it is Possibe.

I have added a line break ('\n') in the label text. still it did not work

```
String description = "22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] split = description.split("(?<=\\G.................................................)");
        for(String s : split){
            sb.append(s).append("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `<h:selectOneMenu>` is translated into a `<select>` HTML element while `<f:selectItem>` and `<f:selectItems>` are translated into `<option>` HTML elements.

Browsers don't manage line-break in these elements. See : [Line Break in HTML Select Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option)

As stated, the only method is to create custom HTML and use JS to make it look like a native `<select>`