# Show parent in label of select option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, simple-form

I have one select box

```
<%=simple_form_for order_item do |oi|%>
  <%= order_item.association :category, label: false, collection: current_company.categories, placeholder: 'Category', input_html: { class: 'form-control form-control-sm drop_down_input order_item_category} %>
<%end%>
```

and this select box is bind with `select2`

currently, when I search anything this shows results like this: -

[image]

But I want to results like show search and with a label that showing item's parent (note: - category has one parent. and one category has many children)

[image]

however I tried with `option_groups` with this the issue is I cant select option_group(which is parent), but I want to select all category.

## Category model

```
belongs_to :parent, class: 'category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
has_many :children, class: 'category'
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Can you please add `category` model definition?

Comment: @MrShemek hi, please have a look to updated question its normally self association of category.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with something like this:

```
<%= order_item.association :category, collection: current_company.categories.collect { |c| [ c.id, "#{c.name} in #{c.parent.name}" ] }, value_method: :first, label_method: :last, placeholder: 'Category', input_html: { class: 'form-control form-control-sm drop_down_input order_item_category} %>
```

This should give you an information about parent in the select's option. I have tested it but without `jquery-select2`.

Then, you will probably have to use some CSS/JS/HTML to move `in ...` to another line. Please take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GXtpC/2099/).

**Edit**

As far as I noticed `jquery-select2` searches in the option's text, so my solution will not work as expected.

For instance: if you have a "Ferrari in Cars" option and you type `Cars` it will display all options where `Cars` is a parent category. If this is something that you would like to avoid, you can change the way of matching results: [doc](https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched)

Comment: thanks for your answer can i add some css on text part of option like this: - `<option value="456">computers <p color="#f3f3f3">in Hardware</p></option>` basically i wanted to add some change in text colour `in ...`   part. i tried to but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I am not sure if simple `<p color>` will work. I think you have to use `templateResult` and `templateSelection` options ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324334/2039726))