# Multiple line Option Text Value if Width is fixed

Tags: html, css

i follwed this link [Line Break in HTML Select Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option) but it didnt helped me as i tried every suggestion that was suitable for my requirement, the question seems simple but can anyone tell me or share me if they have implemented then how?

I'm sharing part of code:

```
<td id="td_User">
<select name="userName" id="userName" required="required"  style="width: 100px">
<option value=" " selected>All</option>
<c:forEach var="map" items="${userList}">
<c:if test="${map.key ne '0'}">
<option value="${map.key }"<c:if test="${map.value eq usrName}">Selected</c:if>>${map.value }</option>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</td>
```

Here, the Option Value is Coming From Database, The issue that is that i hv to keep Select tag width 100Px,

```
  <select name="userName" id="userName" required="required"  style="width: 100px">
```

But When Drop down comes, Dropdown box width depends upon the data, i.e; Option value.
I need to fix this Dropdown Box width:100px Containing Data,but if data is Containing more words then it should be shown in multiple Line.

Comment: Just like this JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/1139/

Comment: But when i try this fiddle example with my code, it gives Error: TypeError: $(...).selectBoxIt is not a function

Comment: What browser are you using? (also the version number is relevant)

Comment: Firefox 47.0.2 and Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) @merosss