# Need to show the ng-option in two lines angular 6

Tags: html, angular, angular-ngselect

I need to show data in select with two lines each. I am using ng-select.

```
          <ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedData" placeholder="Select Data">
            <div *ngFor="let data of Data">
              <ng-option [value]="data.id">
                {{data.name}} - {{data.price | currency}} 
                {{data.description}} - {{data.code}}
              </ng-option>
            </div>
          </ng-select>
```

I am using ng-select and trying to show the data in ng-option, it is showing the data in one line. already tried br and /n.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't!

None browser will allow doing this formatting of text.

But yes you can use some another alternate for show text if needed may be using `title` which will show data as a tooltip.

Comment: Yes, i have used different approach in order to present the data.

Comment: Great, you can edit my answer if you want to add some potential to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported.
Try this instead,

```
Data.forEach(element => {
    dropDownDataSource.push(id: element.name, value: element.name)
    dropDownDataSource.push(id: element.description, value: element.description)
});



<ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedData" placeholder="Select Data">
    <option *ngFor="let data of dropDownDataSource" value="{{data.value}}">
        {{data.id}}
    </option>  
</ng-select>
```