# Select2 options with description

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the **jQuery Select2** plugin for select boxes. Now, I want to add a description to each option. When I open the select box I see the following text:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
```

But instead, I want to see something like:

```
One
*Description for option One*
Two
*Description for option Two*
Three
*Description for option Three*
Four
*Description for option Four*
```

Does someone know how this can be approach?

Here is my full script:

```js
$.fn.select2.defaults = $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults,
{
    allowClear: true,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    placeholder: 'Select...',
    minimumResultsForSearch: 15
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var configParamsObj = {
        placeholder: '',
        minimumResultsForSearch: 3
    };

    $("#vat").select2(configParamsObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="vat" name="vat">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be using `disabled` options below every available option. Even more, you can customize the style of those disabled options using the `templateResult` option of the `select2` plugin, like shown on the below example:

```js
$.fn.select2.defaults = $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults,
{
    allowClear: true,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    placeholder: 'Select...',
    minimumResultsForSearch: 15
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var configParamsObj = {
        placeholder: '',
        minimumResultsForSearch: 3,
        templateResult: function(data, container)
        {
            // Read and propagate the class attribute of elements.

            if (data.element)
                $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));

            return data.text;
        }
    };

    $("#vat").select2(configParamsObj);
});
```

```css
.opt-desc
{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: skyblue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="vat" name="vat" style="width:50%">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option class="opt-desc" disabled>Description of option One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option class="opt-desc" disabled>Description of option Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option class="opt-desc" disabled>Description of option Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option class="opt-desc" disabled>Description of option Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[Line Break in HTML Select Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option)

The summary is that browsers don't natively support drop down options breaking over two lines, which I think is what you want here. As a consolation prize, could you add the description as a tool tip like this?

```
<option value="1" title="*Description for option One*">One</option>
```