# Is there possibility to break line in select?

Tags: html, css, styles, html-select

i'm trying to break the line in styled select.

I've styled it using this: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/select-css.html

I'm providing image below how it looks right now (on the left) and how it should look like (on the right).
[image]

I've already tryed to use break-word, line-break - but nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line Break in HTML Select Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option)

Comment: I am not sure, why you have to use `break-word` and other properties, is it a `div` you're using? if so it should take of this automatically.

Comment: Daniel Sixl - yes i think is the same - sorry