# Django ChoiceField is not rendering /n as a new line?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to display strings with  new lines in ChoiceField form but it is rendered in just one line.

```
s = "name: x \n  email: x@gmail.com"
```

But after it's rendered it's showing like this:

```
name: x  email: x@gmail.com
```

And not like this:

```
name: x 
email: x@gmail.com
```

Please suggest me some workaround in the backend and not in the frontend part.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a newline in the label of a select/dropdown option?

Comment: @IainShelvington, yes. I want to add new line inside the label of select.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington , from the Stackoverflow post that you shared I discovered the closest we can do is to use "title attribute". Now my question is how to add title attribute in django ChoiceField.