# Change height of select to fit option

Tags: html, css, select

I have a select with a fixed width but I need to change the height of the select to fit the all the options, so that the entire option text is shown rather than it being cut off. I have tried setting the height to an arbitary value of `80px` and adding `whitespace:pre-wrap` which works but this means that the shorter options are obviously still 80px tall so they take up more room than they need to.
Below is an example of a select that I am trying to work with.

```html
<select style='padding: 0.5rem; white-space:pre-wrap; width: 100%; height:80px;'>
  <option>Text 1</option>
  <option>Text 1 Lots of additional text that needs additional room</option>
  <option>Text 1 Some extra text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with the standard `<select>` tag, you may need to look into a replacement like Select2: https://github.com/select2

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look around to see if there are any react packages like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864238/line-break-in-html-select-option There's a few work-arounds that might work for you but they produce a different result too so maybe worth giving those a shot as well. Most of them utilize some form of jquery though so it's not really a direct answer to your question unfortunately.