# HTML select dropdown going off screen

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Considering the following code:

```html
<div style="float: left;">
  <select style="width: 160px;">
    <option>asd flkjh asdfkljha sdlkfjhasldjkfh aslkjdfh asjdhf alksjdhl k</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div style="float: right;">
  <select style="width: 160px;">
    <option>asd flkjh asdfkljha sdlkfjhasldjkfh aslkjdfh asjdhf alksjdhl k</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When opening the right selectbox, the contents of the dropdown go off the screen. Also when the list would be longer, you would not be able to scroll through the list (only with mousewheel and keyboard, but the scrollbar is invisible)

Is there a fix for this? Ofcourse you could set a width / max-width on the options, but that would cut off the contents of the option element. Any suggestions?

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: Set this code up locally, and i really don't see what is the problem. In firefox and safari, you get some really long menus.. is this what you mean by "falling off the screen" ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aQYnF/ in FF4 the first options goes out of the screen

Comment: "fall off the screen" is a Dutch aphorism, which should not be translated into English... Excuse me :) The jsfiddle example is exactly what I meant, the first option is only visible partially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean the right side of the select box is not visible so the user cannot use the scroll-bar.

You have 2 potential options that I can see outside of changing to a JavaScript solution, the first is to repostition the elements to allow for longer content.

The second is to specify the width of the element to a percentage value as below, the downside is the width of the select element will be dynamically changed and you will lose some design control.

```html
<div style="float: right;">
  <select style="width:100%">
    <option width="">asd flkjh asdfkljha sdlkfjhasldjkfh aslkjdfh asjdhf alksjdhl k</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I did a quick test in Chrome and Firefox, you can use what ever percentage value you want to, I tested on 100% and 50%, on 50% - depending on the nature of the content or any place holder values like "--SELECT--", the element will only show half the length of the longest item.

I would look into most likely look into jQuery plugins or other JavaScripts for a better solution depending on my needs at the time.

Comment: Thanks, I feared already that I had to use JavaScript to fix this issue. Repositioning or enlarging the selectbox is not an option in my UI.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue recently (with Firefox) - the open select menu would go beyond the bounds of the desktop screen.

My solution was to copy the option content into the title attribute. And also update the select title on change, so hovering over the option or select will show a tooltip within the browser window - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/15vt3ohx/1/).

```
var $select = $('select');

$select
    .on('change', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            // use replace to remove extra white (if desired)
            txt = $this.find('option:selected').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        // add title to select
        $this.attr('title', txt);
    })
    .change()
    .find('option').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // add title to each option, so it works on hover
        $this.attr('title', $this.text());
    });
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Although it doesn't solve the problem of the options going off the screen, making the vertical scroll bar inaccessible.  These kind of popup menus shouldn't clip themselves on the edge of the screen, so this is probably a bug in the OS or the browser.  System-level context menus such as the select drop down, which extend outside the browser window should be automatically repositioned and resized to remain within the display. It's definitely repositioning it in some cases, but it's just not sized properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer

[Are Multi-line Options in Html Select Tags Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165358/multi-line-options-in-htm-select)

With pure HTML and a select it is impossible to auto-wrap the content of an option in multiple lines (so it would not go off the screen)