# How can I build a <select> with multiline options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to build a multi-line select control. All the `<option>`'s where text is wider than 300px (for example) become to have the necessary lines to don't exceed the mentioned limit.

These images speak for themselves:

[image: http://home.comcast.net/~ephmynus/select1.jpg]
[image: http://home.comcast.net/~ephmynus/select2.jpg]

---

First of all I tried this, but does not work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            option{
                width: 100px; 
                white-space: wrap;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option>I'm short</option>
            <option>I'm medium text</option>
            <option>I'm a very very very very very very very very very long text</option>
        </select>   
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using bootstrap framework and I thought that maybe I could use dropdown control to obtain the result. I've tried setting the max-width CSS property, but it does not work too...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you cannot word-wrap select options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list. and all the internet? how facetious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<option>` tags have limited styling capabilities and do not support formatting.

You can use a [JavaScript-based alternative](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-form-select-boxes/). There are plenty out there if you look around.

Comment: Adding, what styling can be done is also erratic and browser-specific.