# jQuery or css to handle long description in select element

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a problem deal with select element in my latest project. The problem is the description inside select element is too long cause layout disrupted. I have a solution to set fixed width for select and option in css like below:

```
select, option {
   width:500px;
}
```

The problem when the user click the select element, the option back to normal width, not the width that I set in my css file.

Print screen image of my system:

[image]

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errorare/VBjCn/1/)!

Comment: you could have given a demo fiddle with your relevent code instead of that screenshot.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh, here is the jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/errorare/VBjCn/. FYI, I only use a normal html select with select,option css code.

Comment: @errorare http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/VBjCn/17/

Comment: @arjuncc it only change <select> width element not <option> width inside the select element. The problem is <option> width that display when the user click the drop down.

Comment: @errorare, do you want to show full content of the option?

Comment: @arjuncc yes full content with fixed width.

Comment: @errorare, sorry to say. Without any plug in its impossible Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165358/multi-line-options-in-htm-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select options are crazy... It is near impossible to control the option width. You cannot even apply `text-overflow:ellipsis`. Some of the option values that you have are very long. Try to trim down your text to some chars and populate in your dropdown, provide a title with the full text with some tooltip plugin like the one in `bootstrap` which will emphasise the title as a popout. Or try using some jquery dropdown plugins like the ones below.

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/
http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/index.html

Comment: Tq @PSCoder. I try follow the way in the link that you suggest. I'll come back with the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
select{
    width:500px;
}
select, option {
    max-width: 500px;
}

select, option:hover {
   max-width:600px;
}

select, option:active {
   max-width:600px;
}
```

it might help if i correctly understand your question

Comment: i also tried it with max width, but it also change the width of drop down if you replace above css attribute width to max-width:600px;

Comment: It only change <select> width element not <option> width inside the select element.

Comment: i updated the css and also checked on your fiddle, now it only changes option width. i test this on my firefox