# How to fix truncated text on <select> element on iOS7

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, ios7, jquery-mobile-select

Is there any way to prevent iOS7 from truncating the text when selecting an option on a html `select` element? iOS7 truncates the text on the options text instead of wrapping it. In my specific case this is totally unusable:

[image]

The above screenshot was taken from a html 5 app built with jQuery Mobile. I should also mention that this issue is not present on iOS6.

Comment: I think that you can't...

Comment: split the options as much u can.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add an empty `optgroup` at the end of the select list:

```
 <select>
  <option selected="" disabled="">Select a value</option>
  <option>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</option>
  <option>Quirky spud boys can jam after zapping five worthy Polysixes</option>
  <option>The wizard quickly jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized</option>
  <option>All questions asked by five watched experts amaze the judge</option>
  <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
 </select>
```

Comment: it looks a little bit like some dirty hack. But works perfectly!

Comment: Jesus, what a weird hack. But as others have said, it works, so *shrug*.

Comment: take from a NAA of @tmwild
`Sorry to post this as an answer rather than a comment (new account) but the accepted solution here will currently cause a problem on ios8 devices. Ios8 struggles with optgroups - find the details below...`

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7848

Comment: Still working on iOS9 (it uses a smaller font size and adds line-breaks when needed)

Comment: Even though the text size decreases, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: yes this is the ONLY solution out there for webapps. it's an absolutely absurd hack for a despicable UI but it works and solves numerous client issues. iOS should simply auto size and wrap text. Android, at least HTC Sense does this in a modern popup screen. So over this horrendous wheel thing. </rant> Cheers!

Comment: It indeed works, but when this hack applied (iOS 12) the checked item remain checked when selecting another item (specifically, if the selected item is out of the view boundary). This is a view glitch; the last clicked item is the one that' selected.

Answer (score 17):

Like the answer above, but add an empty optgroup for every select in the document using JS:

```
// iOS 7 hack: Add an optgroup to every select in order to avoid truncating the content
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod touch);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)) {
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++ ){
        selects[i].appendChild(document.createElement("optgroup"));
    }
}
```

Hope this comes in handy to someone having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfect for me IOS 10(current last version) and bellow

Comment: can't believe this fix is still working / needed in 2021 on IOS13.