# Security questions select menu cut off on small screens

Tags: forms, select, input

I have a set of security questions wrapped in a select menu. They are questions such as:

- What is your mother's maiden name?
- What is your dog's name?
- Etc.

On iOS and Android small screens, the text inside the select menu is being trimmed at the right edge. So, the text looks more like:

> What is your mothe...
>
> What is your dog...

My question is, how do you combat this? Is there a native way of reading long select menu options that I'm not aware of?

I should mention that I'd rather not add something like jQuery UI to the project at this point if at all possible (it may not be).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found the best solution was to [do what was listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398154/how-to-fix-truncated-text-on-select-element-on-ios7) and add an empty `<optgroup>` in the select menu. It doesn't look the greatest and is somewhat hacky, but it appears to work for now:

**iOS and HTML**
[image: iOS + HTML screenshot]

**Android stock 4.4.2**
[image: Android stock 4.4.2 screenshot]