# How to add line break in parameter prompt text

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a parameter in an SSRS report for which I need to add a little comment for the users. I need to add line break within the comment so the message does not show in one long line.

I have added line breaks in the in the XML code by just going on the next line where i want the line break to show. So far it's working when I run the report in visual studio, but it shows in one line when run in the browser.

[image]

How it show in VS

[image]

Any suggestion on how I should handle this?

Comment: This sounds like a lot of trouble.  Much better to just have link to another report or page that shows a table of all possible parameters and their respective comments.

Comment: Not possible. This uses HTML selects which don't support this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165358/are-multi-line-options-in-html-select-tags-possible

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line break in the *Tooltip* expression. I know it works for textboxes in SSRS but I am not sure how it is with parameters. For example:

```
="Line 1" & VbCrlf & "Line 2"
```