# Blazorise Select component List long text issue

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I'm beginner to **Blazorise** and I used the [Select component](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/select), so when I using the long text in for select list, the select list not showing correctly , please look at the attached image. any solution for this to wrap the long text select option?

image description here

[image]

**Code here**

```
<Field ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is4.OnTablet.Is12.OnMobile.Is12.OnDesktop.Is4.OnWidescreen.Is4.OnFullHD">
<Select TValue="int">
    <SelectItem Value="1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</SelectItem>
    <SelectItem Value="2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</SelectItem>
    <SelectItem Value="3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</SelectItem>
    <SelectItem Value="4">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and tLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</SelectItem>
</Select></Field>
```

Comment: If you need multiline options, I suggest that you use the `DropDown` component instead. `SelectItem` creates an `<option>`  tag internally and it's not possible to style those elements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165395/10839134

Comment: Use CSS selector and wrap it

Comment: @charithsuminda I put like this      `option {
 max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    white-space: normal;
}` but not work

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Hi, did you meant multiselect option?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge browsers ignore styles for `<option>` tag so CSS like following won't work.

```
option {  
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    white-space: normal; 
}
```

As a workaround I suggest to use the [Dropdown](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/dropdown) component instead. Here is an example:

```
<Field ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is4.OnTablet.Is12.OnMobile.Is12.OnDesktop.Is4.OnWidescreen.Is4.OnFullHD">
    <Dropdown>
        <DropdownToggle Color="Color.Light" Width="Width.Is100">
            @(_selectedValue.HasValue ? _selectedValue : "Select item")
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu Style="max-width: 100%;">
            <DropdownItem Value="1" Class="text-truncate" Clicked="() => OnItemClicked(1)">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </DropdownItem>

            <DropdownDivider />

            <DropdownItem Value="2" Class="text-truncate" Clicked="() => OnItemClicked(2)">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </DropdownItem>

            <DropdownDivider />

            <DropdownItem Value="3" Class="text-truncate" Clicked="() => OnItemClicked(3)">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </DropdownItem>

            <DropdownDivider />

            <DropdownItem Value="4" Class="text-truncate" Clicked="() => OnItemClicked(4)">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and tLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
</Field>

@code {
    private int? _selectedValue;

    private void OnItemClicked(int value)
    {
        _selectedValue = value;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Dropdown]