# How can I vertically scale a select option when it overflows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in the following HTML, there is a very long string inside the option element. Is there any way to scale the option element vertically when it overflows, so that the user can see all the text content within the box?

```css
select {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

option {
  white-space: normal;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1" id="purchaserSelect">
  <option>CCCCInvesDD, LC, and Life Company, ASAA Funding, AAAA Acquisition, LLC, BCATAAAA, BCAT 2020-3TT, AAAA, LLC,DDDD Investment Holdings LLC,CCCC Realty Holdings LLC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: One option is to convert the options to HTML via javascript. So that way you have more control over the output. There are many plugins that accomplish this so you wouldn't even have to build one from scratch.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment ,can you give me example ?

Comment: Consider using a [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns) or other structure which gives you more formatting control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for multi-line options, it is not possible with HTML select element. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165395/21598034).

However, it is possible to reduce font-size if the option overflows:

```
var windowWidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var option = document.querySelector("option");
console.log(select.scrollWidth);


  if(select.scrollWidth>windowWidth){
    option.style["font-size"]="0.5rem";
  }
```